# Call a JSP page from a standalone Java class (Without Servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, call

I want to call a JSP page (Eg: http://www.google.jsp) from a standalone Java class. I don't want to use servlet. HttpURLConnection doesn't seem to work. It is not taking me to the JSP page. My print statement in the JSP is not getting called when I use below code to call the JSP but the print statement is available if I call the JSP URL separately. Tried searching but no clear answer.

My code snippet using HttpURLConnection is below:

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);
boolean redirect = false;
// normally, 3xx is redirect
int status = conn.getResponseCode();
if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
        || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
    redirect = true;
}
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);
System.out.println("Response Message ... " + conn.getResponseMessage());
if (redirect) {
    // get redirect url from "location" header field
    String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
    // get the cookie if need, for login
    String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
    // open the new connnection again
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
    System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);
}
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    html.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
System.out.println("Done")
```

Output:

```
sResultsURL....http://www.google.jsp
Request URL ... http://www.google.jsp
Response Code ... 200
Response Message ... OK
Done
```

Comment: *My print statement in the JSP is not getting called when I use below code to call the JSP*... could you explain exactely what you do, what happens and what you would expect?

Comment: My wild guess is that you probably want to **use** the content of the `html` `StringBuffer`? Also consider using a `StringBuilder`

Comment: When I use HttpURLConnection, the Sysout statement that I have added in the JSP is not getting printed. Whereas if I call the JSP URL directly, its getting printed.

I want to call my JSP from the Java class.

Comment: You don't need all that redirection stuff. It will do that by default.

Answer (score 0):

I've executed your code and it works. Just notice that I've changed only

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

to

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

This is the only code of my jsp:

```
<% System.out.println("writing"); %>
```

Also, adding this to your java class, you can log the content of the jsp to ensure you are calling to the right url:

```
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

BufferedReader buffer = null;
buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-9"));

StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer(); 
int byteRead;
while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1) {
    builder.append((char) byteRead);
}
buffer.close();
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: And writing got printed?


My code in local was actually declared this way only

URL obj = new URL(url);

Comment: Yes, the text appears in the java console. Why don't you try to print in the java class the content of the jsp to ensure you are calling it?